# how do I Increase post width in wordpress blog

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width, blogs

I've been trying to increase the width of the post container in my theme.
The thing is that, I can't seem to get it working. I've tried editing my style.css, but it just doesn't work.

I have added a RIGHT sidebar via "STYLE" plugin.Everything seems fine. I have tried increasing the content widht.. didn't work.
I've got a child theme, so, it's all good.

Here are the screen shots to my page :-

[image]

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without seeing the code for your theme or the webpage itself.

Comment: Here's the CSS :- http://pastebin.com/KGXzzTpj

Comment: How useful do you think the CSS is without the HTML code? You should paste the relevant code into your question and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Nobody will help you if you don't even put in a little effort to prepare your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally.. I got it to work..

```
.content-sidebar,.primary-sidebar {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}
```

Had to adjust the paddings on the right sidebar... edited the style.css file...